# Distinguishable color generation in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

I would like to know if there is a simple algorithm (or jQuery plugin) to select distinguishable colors, up to about 20 different colors. If there is not, where can I find an array of distinguishable colors that I could use directly ?

My use case is to generate different colors for pie charts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My idea is to start from [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color model and walk around the perimeter (hue) with maximal saturation and value:

```
function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
  //... see e.g.: http://snipplr.com/view/14590
}

function distinctColors(count) {
    var colors = [];
    for(hue = 0; hue < 360; hue += 360 / count) {
        colors.push(hsvToRgb(hue, 100, 100));
    }
    return colors;
}
```

The `distinctColors(10)` produces:

```
[[255, 0, 0], [255, 153, 0], [204, 255, 0], [51, 255, 0], [0, 255, 102], [0, 255, 255], [0, 102, 255], [51, 0, 255], [204, 0, 255], [255, 0, 153]]
```

Hard to tell by only looking at RGB values, but they should be as different as possible. I have taken the `hsvToRgb()` implementation from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/14590).

Comment: +1 This is the approach I use here: http://graphicdivine.co.uk/timeline/ .  Worth mentioning that the saturation and brightness can be tweaked by adjusting the two '100's downwards.

Comment: Also, the variable `saturation` should probably be named `hue`, just for clarity.

Comment: @graphicdivine: of course, corrected, thanks! BTW feel free to edit someone else's answers if the mistake is that obvious :-).

Answer (score 2):

You can use eg. [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/).

I do not know about any JavaScript snippet that does that automatically, but you can create one if you properly define the term of "*distinguishable colors*".

There is also a default [list of 16 basic colors in CSS3 (from W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/):

[image]

You can use them and add as many other colors your like for your own usage.

Answer (score 1):

As temporary solution, I picked up colors from the Wikipedia article on [web colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors):

```
var colors = [
    '#0000FF', //blue
    '#FFFF00', //yellow
    '#008000', //green
    '#FFA500', // orange
    '#FF0000', //red
    '#800080', //purple
    '#808000', //olive
    '#00FF00', //lime
    '#800000', //maroon
    '#00FFFF', //aqua
    '#008080', //team
    '#000080', //navy
    '#FF00FF', //fushua
    '#808080' //gray
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Javascript library for this. You can use [colorchain.js](https://github.com/alexibility/colorchain.js) to generate a sequence of colors with varying hues.